# How to deal with AffineTransform in Android?

Tags: java, android, transform, rotation

Specifically I'm wondering how to do something similar to the rotate method.

`public void rotate(double theta)`  - to be more specific.

I have some code that I want to convert to Android:

```
if(getIncr() == 0)
    affineTransform.rotate(0.0);
else 
    affineTransform.rotate(otherVal);

font = myFont.deriveFont(affineTransform);
```

I was doing a little reading on SO and I believe that I'll need to use a Matrix and possibly the paint and canvas class to achieve this.

Could someone shed some light on the topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a Matrix or the various Canvas methods that let you change the transform.